# Adição de valores a uma variável do C++

Tags: c++, variáveis, operadores, estilo-de-codificação

Para uma variável em C++, devemos dar um valor a ela em algum momento do programa, mas é melhor colocar na criação da variável ou depois, qual a melhor opção?

Eu gostaria de saber, pois por mim acho melhor colocar durante a criação quando é uma variável simples, mas quando vou ver outros programas de outras pessoas sempre colocam separado.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para qualquer linguagem, a não ser que ela forneça um bom motivo, em quase todas as situações, é melhor atribuir um valor logo na declaração dela.

Especialmente em linguagens como C ou C++ que não garantem um valor padrão para a criação da variável, se não fizer isso terá um lixo e isso pode causar problemas se o programador não garantir a inicialização mais pra frente, o que ele pode se perder. Mesmo em outras linguagens o valor padrão para alguns tipos, especialmente os por referência, podem não ser uma boa ideia.

No passado até podia fazer mais sentido em alguns casos de C, Pascal e outras linguagens que optaram por permitir a declaração apenas antes de todo o resto do código. Desta forma há situações que você não tem o valor ainda para fazer uma atribuição que faça sentido. Mesmo assim o ideal é dar um valor temporário para garantir que não pegará lixo. Porém em casos que se busca extrema performance essa inicialização temporária é um desperdício que faz sentido ser evitado. Hoje praticamente não há linguagem que não permita a declaração só quando a variável é realmente necessária e tem um valor conhecido adequado para ela.

Para saber quando deve ter alguma exceção e esta regra é preciso estudar profundamente toda computação e ganhar muita experiência com vários cenários. Na dúvida, atribua o valor imediatamente.

Muito código que vê por aí, especialmente na internet são feitos por quem não aprendeu direito. E provavelmente aprendeu com quem também não aprendeu direito. E torna-se o telefone sem fio. Por isso é preciso muito cuidado com o que acha de informação por aí.

Algumas pessoas ensinaram certo, quando era necessário, mas o mundo mudou e as pessoas continua repetindo o que acontecia no passado e hoje é considerado errado. Quem faz isso não entende o que está fazendo, apenas repete uma receita de bolo pronta para uso, não entende as implicações disso.

Se fosse C, até teria um motivo para declarar tudo antes, manter compatibilidade com compiladores bem antigos ou menos poderosos que não implementaram C99. Ainda assim na maioria dos casos não faz mais sentido.